# RegOpenKeyEx in VBA returns Err 5 (Error_NoAccess) because of UAC high

Tags: vba, excel, registry, uac

I am trying to read a registry entry in under Local machine from a xla. If UAC is high the funcion RegOpenKeyEx fails to read registry. Is there any way to get the permission(via code).

```
rc = RegOpenKeyEx(KeyRoot, KeyName, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, hKey)
```

KeyRoot  is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

KeyName is "SOFTWARE\XYZ"

Note: My code works without any issue - When UAC is low.
OS : Win 7, 
Office : Tested in 2007 and 2010 - both had teh same issue.

Comment: Please show your code, and tells us what versions of Excel and OS you are using

Comment: You could try a different security level. [See this MS site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks chris neilsen,

I used KEY_READ access prievilage as mentioned in this site.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx